# Can i access profiles of people who like a facebook page(not owned by me)

Tags: facebook, api

hey i was wondering if there is a way to access profiles of people who have liked a specific page which is not owned by me and probably send them a message???

Answer (score 0):

No, that is whole point of Facebook's privacy controls. A user must give your app permission to contact them.