# Is there any way to get facebook user id , who liked a page?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

In [Graph API Explorer page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/#!/tools/explorer), with this command 'rahmanismcom', i can get total number of likes received.
And with this command 'rahmanismcom/likes' i can get likes details which page liked.
Is there any way to get get user details atleast their id , who liked this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not quite possible unless you have special permissions on that page:

[Can i access profiles of people who like a facebook page(not owned by me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536631/can-i-access-profiles-of-people-who-like-a-facebook-pagenot-owned-by-me)

There are some workarounds though:

[Facebook API: Get fans of / people who like a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018849/facebook-api-get-fans-of-people-who-like-a-page)